# promise-mysql - single catch of the end

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I use [*promise-mysql*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) and I try use only one *catch* block in chain promises but when I throw error in on of *then* block *catch* block didn't react of this error.

```js
_this._mailboxDbPool._dbPool.getConnection().then(function (connection) {
  connection.query(_this.checkMailboxExist({
    username: options.username,
    domain: options.domain
  }))
    //  Check mailbox exist
    .then(function (result) {
        throw new Error('Teset error');
        return connection.query(queryDomainExist);
    });
})
.catch((err) => {
   //  Don't react
   console.log("Fake error");
})
```

I also can return result with connection as Object in the first *then* block but it will сumbersome and not elegantly. How rewrite code with use only one catch block for *promise-mysql*?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't return the promise from your inner function. `return connection.query.....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to catch it in inner block first.

```
    _this._mailboxDbPool._dbPool.getConnection().then(function (connection){connection.query(_this.checkMailboxExist({
username: options.username,
domain: options.domain
   }))
//  Check mailbox exist
.then(function (result) {
    throw new Error('Teset error');
    return connection.query(queryDomainExist);
}).catch((err) => {throw err;});
  }).catch((err) => {
  //  Don't react
   console.log("Fake error");
  })
```

Comment: I also have idea declare *connection* variable before start dbConnection and use this connection later withou nested promise

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting Promises you can structure then this way.
Here there is single Promise chain and errors will be caught in `catch`.

```
_this._mailboxDbPool._dbPool.getConnection()
  .then(function(connection) {
    return connection.query(_this.checkMailboxExist({
      username: options.username,
      domain: options.domain
    }))
  })
  //  Check mailbox exist
  .then(function(result) {
    throw new Error('Teset error');
    return connection.query(queryDomainExist);
  });
  .catch((err) => {
    //  Don't react
    console.log("Fake error");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise in your first function to allow chaining to occur. Here's some sample code with your `getConnection` and `query` methods mocked:

```
function getConnection() {
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function query() {
    return Promise.resolve();
}

getConnection().then(() => {
    return query().then(() => {
      throw new Error('Bleh');
  });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Oh no', err);
});
```

Comment: `connection.query` return promise and like you say I can use single promise chain. And also I need use previous connection in the following `then` blocks. `then` can return only signle argument and I don't wanna return Object data with query result and connection. I think abut declaring `connection` variable before promise and then use it in `then` block latter. What do you think?